# ASP.NET MVC - Checkbox text attribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc, checkbox

I'm drawing some checkboxes in a loop and i want to set the text attribute based on the objects that I'm iteration with the loop.

I've something like this:

`<asp:CheckBox ID=`"CheckBox1`" runat=`"server`" Text=`"`<%= Html.Encode(item.nome) %>`" Checked="true"/>

The problem is that the Html.Encode(item.nome) appears as plain text and if i dont use the quotation marks i get an error.

Comment: Please, rename this question. It's little confusing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Alternatively, use the `Html.CheckBox` helper.

```
<%= Html.CheckBox( "CheckBox1", true ) %> <%= Html.Encode(Item.none) %>
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't use the `<asp:CheckBox>` control - create a standard html checkbox:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="cb" checked="checked"><%= Html.Encode(item.nome) %></input>
```

Comment: "Don't use the <asp:CheckBox> control"...  In an MVC application.

Comment: Of course - I assumed that was understood, considering the question was specific for ASP.NET MVC.

Answer (score 1):

You can't mix ASP.NET control tags with the `<%= %>` syntax.  You have two options here:

Use raw HTML for your checkbox, then you can use `<%= %>` just fine.  This style fits better with ASP.NET MVC.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="cb" checked="checked"><%= Html.Encode(item.nome) %></input>
```

Or you can use ASP.NET control-friendly data binding syntax:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Html.Encode(Container.DataItem, "nome") %>' Checked="true"/>
```

But to use the data-binding syntax you need a data source control and to be inside a Repeater control.  See [ASP.NET data binding](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307860) for more information.